# No implementation for play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi was bound

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm working on a back-end project using Scala, the Play Framework, and the IntelliJ IDE just to practice, I'm new to these technologies.

I added the Reactive Mongo dependency to the build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.6-play26"
)
```

What I get is this error :

```
No implementation for play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi was bound
```

When I hover the mouse on

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.6-play26"
```

This little text displays:

Unknown artifact. Not resolved or indexed.

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE:**

When i refresh the project by hitting option + enter on the dependency, the "Event log" shows this :

[`warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible: [warn] * com.google.guava:guava:22.0 is selected over 19.0 [warn] +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.7 (depends on 22.0) [warn] +- com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0 (depends on 19.0) [warn] * com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.6 is selected over 2.4.19 [warn] +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.12:2.6.7 (depends on 2.5.6) [warn] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.12:10.0.10 (depends on 2.4.19) [warn] * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.6 is selected over {2.4.14, 2.4.19} [warn] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.6 () (depends on 2.5.6) [warn] +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.7 (depends on 2.5.6) [warn] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.12:2.5.6 () (depends on 2.5.6) [warn] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.12:10.0.10 (depends on 2.4.19) [warn] +- org.reactivemongo:reactivemongo_2.12:0.12.6 () (depends on 2.4.14) [warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings`

Comment: Check the conf, see https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/reactivemongo-demo-app

Comment: @cchantep I already did it ! Still doesn't work

Comment: Come on why would someone downvote this ? Isn't it explicit enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `0.12.6-play26` version of the plugin published in the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cplay2-reactivemongo). You probably want version `0.12.7-play26`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.7-play26"
)
```

Comment: Thanks four your answer, I actually followed the reactive mongo doc http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html

I made the change you said but it still doesn't work

Comment: So why mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like error from dependency injection. Have you followed the [tutorial](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html) you referenced fully including the "Setup" part?

> Thus, the dependency injection can be configured, so that the your controllers are given the new ReactiveMongo API. First, Add the line bellow to application.conf:

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, i already did this but it still doesn't work

Comment: @AzoulayJason, So you did that and also configured `mongodb.uri` in the `application.conf` and still got the error?

Answer (score 0):

First be sure you add this to you build.sbt:

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Without this the controller is static and not going to dependency injection.
Then I had the same issue as you and it was because of a bad configuration on application.conf. I feel when the config is not good there is a silence error when trying to create the mongo API instance and then is also not able to inject into the controller.